# How to loop a audio in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using phonegap 2.2.0. I tried some code to loop the audio for playing without interruption but it is **not working on my android device**. It plays only once. Here is my code:

```
 


    function playAudio(url) {

        var my_media = new Media(url,
            function() {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: "+err);
            },
            function(status) {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Status: "+status);
            }
        });

        // Play audio
        my_media.play({numberOfLoops:99});
    }
```

Can you tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping is not supported for Android yet in Phonegap - so numberOfLoops does nothing except on iOS devices.

Comment: `var myMedia;

var loop = function (status) {
    if (status === Media.MEDIA_STOPPED) {
        myMedia.play();
    }
};

myMedia = new Media("/audio/my.mp3", null, null, loop);
myMedia.play();`

Answer (score 12):

Listen to status change and start paying on MEDIA_STOPPED. If you want the user to stop the sound, use snd.pause() and not snd.stop()

This worked for me:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    var getPhoneGapPath = function() {
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
        return path;
    };

    var snd = null;

    function onDeviceReady(){
        snd = new Media( getPhoneGapPath() + "sound/funk_game_loop.mp3", onSuccess, onError, onStatus);
        snd.play();
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    function onSuccess() {
    }
    // onError Callback 
    function onError(error) {
    }
    // onStatus Callback 
    function onStatus(status) {
        if( status==Media.MEDIA_STOPPED ) {
            snd.play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It has some latency though

Comment: I am using this solution but every once in a while music will just stop. it is as if sometimes the onStatus is not getting fired. Anyone else seeing this problem?

Comment: It's some delay time when start a new loop. But it works for me.