# Phaser HTML5 app cannot play sound after porting by Phonegap Cloud Build

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, phaser-framework

This's a simple Phaser audio example. It works well on my Android web browser. However, it's muted after porting to Android app by Phonegap cloud build.

I know how to play sound (and loop) in Phonegap app ([How to loop a audio in phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927316/how-to-loop-a-audio-in-phonegap)) but don't know how to apply it into the Phaser JS framework.

Here's the ported app. I can install and run it but without sound. Do I miss something or Phonegap Cloud Build does support the WebAudio in Phaser JS?

https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1783695/

My `config.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <widget id="com.phaser.phasersound" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>Phaser sound complete</name>
<description>
   Phaser sound phonegap
</description>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="1"/>

<!--
  If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
  following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
  permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
-->
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  </widget>
```

The source code is: (I changed the local audio files from local to github links to run on code snippet)

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(600, 800, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });

function preload() {

 game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    
    //have the game centered horizontally
    game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
    game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;

    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#414040';

    // I changed the local audio files from local to github links to run on code snippet

    /*
    game.load.audio('explosion', 'assets/audio/SoundEffects/explosion.mp3');
    game.load.audio('sword', 'assets/audio/SoundEffects/sword.mp3');
    game.load.audio('blaster', 'assets/audio/SoundEffects/blaster.mp3');
    */

    game.load.audio('explosion', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nguoianphu/phaser-sound-complete-phonegap/master/www/assets/audio/SoundEffects/explosion.mp3');
    game.load.audio('sword', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nguoianphu/phaser-sound-complete-phonegap/master/www/assets/audio/SoundEffects/sword.mp3');
    game.load.audio('blaster', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nguoianphu/phaser-sound-complete-phonegap/master/www/assets/audio/SoundEffects/blaster.mp3');

}

var explosion;
var sword;
var blaster;

var text;

var text1;
var text2;
var text3;

function create() {



    var style = { font: "65px Arial", fill: "#52bace", align: "center" };
    text = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, 100, "decoding", style);
    text.anchor.set(0.5);

    explosion = game.add.audio('explosion');
    sword = game.add.audio('sword');
    blaster = game.add.audio('blaster');

    //  Being mp3 files these take time to decode, so we can't play them instantly
    //  Using setDecodedCallback we can be notified when they're ALL ready for use.
    //  The audio files could decode in ANY order, we can never be sure which it'll be.

    game.sound.setDecodedCallback([ explosion, sword, blaster ], start, this);

}

var keys;

function start() {

    text.text = 'Press 1, 2 or 3';

    var style = { font: "48px Arial", fill: "#cdba52", align: "center" };

    text1 = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, 250, "Blaster: Stopped", style);
    text1.anchor.set(0.5);

    text2 = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, 350, "Explosion: Stopped", style);
    text2.anchor.set(0.5);

    text3 = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, 450, "Sword: Stopped", style);
    text3.anchor.set(0.5);

    explosion.onStop.add(soundStopped, this);
    sword.onStop.add(soundStopped, this);
    blaster.onStop.add(soundStopped, this);

    keys = game.input.keyboard.addKeys({ blaster: Phaser.Keyboard.ONE, explosion: Phaser.Keyboard.TWO, sword: Phaser.Keyboard.THREE });

    keys.blaster.onDown.add(playFx, this);
    keys.explosion.onDown.add(playFx, this);
    keys.sword.onDown.add(playFx, this);

    //  And for touch devices you can also press the top, middle or bottom of the screen
    game.input.onDown.add(onTouch, this);

}

function onTouch(pointer) {

    var b = game.height / 3;

    if (pointer.y < b)
    {
        playFx(keys.blaster);
    }
    else if (pointer.y > b * 2)
    {
        playFx(keys.sword);
    }
    else
    {
        playFx(keys.explosion);
    }

}

function playFx(key) {

    switch (key.keyCode)
    {
        case Phaser.Keyboard.ONE:
            text1.text = "Blaster: Playing";
            blaster.play();
            break;

        case Phaser.Keyboard.TWO:
            text2.text = "Explosion: Playing";
            explosion.play();
            break;

        case Phaser.Keyboard.THREE:
            text3.text = "Sword: Playing";
            sword.play();
            break;
    }

}

function soundStopped(sound) {

    if (sound === blaster)
    {
        text1.text = "Blaster: Complete";
    }
    else if (sound === explosion)
    {
        text2.text = "Explosion: Complete";
    }
    else if (sound === sword)
    {
        text3.text = "Sword: Complete";
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.js"></script>
```

### UPDATE 2015-12-01

Here is my completed source code. It has both .mp3 and .ogg sound files. You can play them on Android native browser (tested on 4.4.4 Samsung E5).

Source: https://github.com/nguoianphu/phaser-sound-complete-phonegap

Here is the ported app on Phonegap. It can display the screen but can't play sounds.
https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1783695/builds

Comment: I can't see, that you are listening for the cordova deviceready-event. On the other hand, it is not a good idea to load an external script, but if you want to do so, you have to whitelisten the url.

Comment: @Joerg, thanks. I edited the Phonegap build link. The app can display and touch on Android but not the audio.

Comment: For my projects i use [this plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio) however, that means that you can't play sounds on a browser. If it works for you, i can expand my comment into a proper answer to show you the details.

Comment: @Apovtx, thanks. But it's really hard to apply your plugin into my Phaser existed source code. I'm looking for an example for Phaser - Phonegap cloud build with sound.

Comment: @Tuan, there are multiple audio bugs in all the platforms. What is your target device? (iPhone, iPad, Android phone, tablet, etc) The version of OS?  (iOS 8, iOS9, SDK-14, SDK-21, etc.) Are you using the standard webview library or the a plugin (like WKWwebview)?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, my target device's Samsung E5 phone (Android 4.4.4). I don't use any plugin, just the standard webview. I can play the Phaser app (touch, display) but it doesn't have sound. If I add the Javascript outside the Phaser for playing sound (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927316/how-to-loop-a-audio-in-phonegap), it works. I think Phonegap doesn't support Phaser sound.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to play the audio with the webview library. It is likely using the [HTML5 API for audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) or [webaudio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). If it is neither of these, then you need to ask the author.

Next, it is not *best practice* to use external source (http:). Your assests (javascript, css, audio files, etc) should live on the device. If you load files from the web, then the sound quality could be poor (or the audio may not play at all - see `whitelist` below). Load from the device.

Android 4.4.4 is Kitkat. The standard webview library was [exchanged for the chromium version](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview.md). This means your audio library might be confused about this or you need to give the library knowledge about this library. This also means your code may not work on devices before 4.4.4. (Mostly, because you cannot test it.)

The link you point to is likely using the core [`media` plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media), even though they dont say so. In addition, the post is over 3 years old. Many thing have changed since them. **NOTE:** you have installed the `media` plugin in your `config.xml`. This is likely why your loop works.

You should start over. You've made many errors. In addition, to all that you have, You will need to implement the `whitelist` plugin (if you are going to import files, or talk to the network).

FIRST TRY this [sample app](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1359137/share) - example plays on Android and iOS. You can download the Android version and test it. The iOS version requires I have your UUID compiled in.

There are [16 audio plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=audio) you can choose from. I know a few do real time audio playback and have better control than the "core" plugin.

You should read:

- [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) - read the **bold** sentences.
- [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)
- HOWTO [Core Plugins Setup](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md)
- [Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7) - just wrote this. It works.
- [Phonegap Demo Apps](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html)
- [Phonegap-Media-Test](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Media-Test) - source code for the example that plays on Android and iOS. You can download the Android version and test it.

---

**UPDATE: 2015-12-01 - 2am** Previously, I had forgotten to add a wild-card (`*`) to the `CSP` meta tag. I am now including this. This meta tag should be added to the header of the `index.html` file that is playing the audio.

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

---

**UPDATE: 2015-12-01 - 3pm**
@Tuan, I've applied all the fixes as outlined in

- [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)
- HOWTO [Core Plugins Setup](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md)
- [Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate7) - just wrote this. It works.

The audio is now working on my ***Android*** *LG Leon/Android 5.1.1*
Truthfully, I would never do this on my own, but your code had enough working that after I tested it on my firefox(v34) browser, I was fairly certain it would work.

**UPDATE:** 2016-04-15
The code has been removed. Ask in the comments, if you need code.

<s>There should be enough code in place for you to work off of.</s>

#### - [Code](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/try-phaser-audio)

#### - [Working Android App](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/1797377/share)

- [Phonegap Build Documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans(en))

Comment: Thanks but I knew Phonegap can play audio. My issue is the Phaser game can play sound after porting by Phonegap. Your example works because it doesn't play the audios by Phaser's functions.

Comment: Apparently I was not clear enough. You know very little about the task ahead, you can spend weeks and months and never find an answer - mostly because you have made bad assumption about Cordova/Phonegap. To fix your problem 1) don't load audio samples from the internet 2) if you must load audio sample internet, you will need to implement the `whitelist` system - otherwise your request will be blocked. 3) the audio library for Phaser may not be supported - you need details on it to make reasonable decisions on it.

Comment: To be extra clear, your post now looks confused. Mostly because you are making bad assumptions. And the addition to not get you any closer to your goal --- which appears to be *to play this Phase audio library*. This is why I posted the links. Best of Luck.

Comment: so sorry for bothering you. My code use local audio, not from internet. I noted it in the code because I want the Phaser game can play in SO code snippet. My question is why the audio can play on web brower with the Phaser library, but after converting it to Android app by Phonegap cloud, it can't? Sorry again for my bad assumptions.

Comment: HMM... I'm not being clear on this. Your browser is not the *webview* library that Cordova/Phonegap uses. You can read my [Notes on webview here](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview.md). In short, every browser uses it's own custom library. (This is the reason for http://caniuse.com) The audio part has been the most inconsistent. The only way to know if an audio library works, is to make the most simple test. Otherwise, you are wasting you time. Best of Luck.

Comment: @Tuan, I found an error in my `CSP` which may explain why you are not getting sound. Previously, I had `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';`. I did not have the wild card for loading the network. It should have been `script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';`. I found this out about an hour ago testing a new App. I am surprised no one has mentioned it until now. Let me know. I'm adding this to my original answer.

Comment: thanks. I tried but it doesn't fix. Here is my repo: https://github.com/nguoianphu/phaser-sound-complete-phonegap

Comment: Okay. thanks give me about 24 hours. I'll let know either way how its goes.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're great! Installed your app on my Android 4.4.4 (Samsung E5): it can detect the internet connection but the sound still deosn't work. Will find a Android 5.1 to test.

Comment: Like I said before, this could be an issue with Android 4.4.4. The sound library could be confused.