# Paypal cordova plugin not getting fired

Tags: angularjs, cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm trying to add Paypal payment method to my app. Here is my JS code.

```
 app.controller('PaypalController',function($scope){
 var output = function() {
    var menuorder = '';
    angular.forEach($scope.filtereditem, function(item) {
      var size = " ";
      var size2 = " ";
      var size3 = " ";
      var size4 = " ";
      var size5 = " ";
      angular.forEach(item.sizes, function(option) {
        if (option && option.active) {
          size += option.name + " in #1<br>";
        }
        if (option && option.active2) {
          size2 += option.name + " in #2<br>";
        }
        if (option && option.active3) {
          size3 += option.name + " in #3<br>";
        }
        if (option && option.active4) {
          size4 += option.name + " in #4<br>";
        }
        if (option && option.active5) {
          size5 += option.name + " in #5<br>";
        }
      });
      menuorder += item.name + "<br/>Side: " + item.type + ", Qty: " + item.qty + ", Modifiers: " + item.modifier + "<br/><br/>Add-Ons:<br/>" + size + size2 + size3 + size4 + size5 + "<br/><br/>";
    });
    return menuorder;
  }
  $scope.filteredmenu = output();
 var init_defer;
    /**
     * Service object
     * @type object
     */
    var service = {
        initPaymentUI: initPaymentUI,
        createPayment: createPayment,
        configuration: configuration,
        onPayPalMobileInit: onPayPalMobileInit,
    };
    function initPaymentUI(){
         var clientIDs = {
       "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
       "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         };
         PayPalMobile.init(clientIDs, onPayPalMobileInit);
     }

   function createPayment() {
     var paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(scope.pricetotal, "0.00", "0.00");
     var payment = new PayPalPayment(scope.pricetotal, "CAD", scope.filteredmenu, "Sale", paymentDetails);
     return payment;
   }
   function configuration() {
     var config = new PayPalConfiguration({merchantName: "SIGNS Store", merchantPrivacyPolicyURL: "https://mytestshop.com/policy", merchantUserAgreementURL: "https://mytestshop.com/agreement"});
     return config;
   }
   function onPayPalMobileInit() {
     PayPalMobile.prepareToRender("PayPalEnvironmentSandbox", configuration());
   }
   function onUserCanceled(result) {
     console.log(result);
   }

    return {
        initPaymentUI : initPaymentUI, 
        createPayment : createPayment,
        configuration : configuration,
        onPayPalMobileInit: onPayPalMobileInit,
    }
    $scope.pay = function(){
                    PayPalMobile.renderSinglePaymentUI(createPayment(), onSuccesfulPayment, onUserCanceled);
}
if(typeof PayPalMobile != 'undefined')
    initPaymentUI();
page_load();
```

My HTML code is as below:

```
        <label>Payment Method:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <md-select placeholder="Select a Payment Method" ng-model="item.payment" ng-change="selectChanged()">
      <md-option aria-label="side set" class="md-accent" value="1">Pay at SIGNS</md-option>
      <md-option aria-label="side set" class="md-accent" value="2">Pay Now</md-option>
    </md-select>
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-controller="PaypalController" ng-show="item.payment==2" ng-click="pay()">
  Pay with PayPal
</md-button>
```

So basically, I have defined $scope.pricetotal as the total price elsewhere and have defined $scope.filteredmenu (which I have shown the code). These are JSON varying elements based on html selection, but end up as a numerical value and string respectively and I'm trying to push them as paypal price and item description.

I have added  to my index and have added the paypal plugin as well using  in my config.xml (I'm using phonegap build). I have also added my paypal sandbox and production IDs. For some reason, however, paypal doesn't seem to fire up at all. Any help with this would be appreciated.

My config.xml as requested:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.signsrestaurant.app"
    versionCode="1.00"
    version   = "1.00">
    <name>Signs Restaurant</name>
    <description>
    Where Noise Meets Silence       </description>
    <author href="http://signsrestaurant.ca" email="gmanikumar@umhs-sk.net">
    Signs Restaurant
    </author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
    <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="true" />
    <gap:platform name="ios" />
    <gap:platform name="android" />
    <gap:platform name="winphone" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" spec="1.3.3" source="pgb" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" spec="0.5.0" source="pgb" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk" version="3.1.9" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.plugin.datepicker" />
    <gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.2" />
    <icon src="images/icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="images/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="images/icon-114.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="images/icon-144.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="images/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="images/icon-120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="images/icon-152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
    <icon src="images/icon-36.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon-48.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon-72.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon-96.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon-144.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon-192.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxxhdpi" />
    <icon src="images/icon-62.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <icon src="images/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-480-320.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-320-480.png" gap:platform="ios" width="480" height="320" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-960-640.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-640-960.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="640" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-1136-640.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-640-1136.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1136" height="640" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-1024-768.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024 " />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-768-1024.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-400-240.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-480-320.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-800-480.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-960-720.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-1920-1080.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="images/splash-800-480.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

My header:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://s.ytimg.com">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<title>Signs Restaurant and Bar</title>  

<!-- All our CSS -->
<!-- onsen-css-components.css is the skin of your app, you can generate one custom skin with this generator: http://components.onsen.io/ -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/onsen-css-components.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/roots.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- These are our JS libraries that make all the magic in our App -->
<script src="js/maps.js"></script>
<script src="js/youtube.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>    
<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular-touch.js"></script>   
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>    
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/paypal-mobile-js-helper.js"></script>  
</head>
```

Comment: Two (2) things. 1) what are you trying to do? what is your final goal? 2) please post your `config.xml`. -- You likely don't have your `whitelist` setup.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I apologize for any vagueness and will try to clarify my attempts: 1) Basically, I have created a working restaurant takeout app and it currently generates an order name and price and sends the same over as an email. My final goal is to add payment via paypal and send the defined order name order price using the plugin (currently testing in sandbox environment). 2) Posted it! If you are taking about the whitelist plugin, I think I have it in, and have defined the meta in index.html as well. I get 0 console errors in chrome inspect. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: There are few errors with the `whitelist`. Sorry I forgot to say, add that information to your original post. Please add the header (meta section). You likely have some mistakes in your `CSP`. Also, I'll look at your `config.xml`. You have things missing.

Comment: Oh, thanks for looking into it! I have added my header section there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is what you need to do.

1. `<feature (...)>` is deprecated for Phonegap Build.
2. You need to update your "core" plugins
3. Your 3rd-party plugins likely need replacement.
4. You need to implement the `whitelist` system

### 1. `<feature (...)>` is deprecated for Phonegap Build.

Don't use it anymore. [SEE](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#012)

**REMOVE**

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>
```

### 2. You need to update your "core" plugins

All core plugins are now on [NPM](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/).
However, FOR NOW, the list (for "core" plugins) you should use is: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/plugins/pluginapis.html
In addition, it is now considered "best practice" for *Phonegap Build* to always use the version you want.

In addition, a little over a week ago there were [some big changes to `config.xml`](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-build/). They don't affect what you DID, but I've given you a headstart, by making the changes for you - where is makes sense.

**REPLACE**

```
<!--
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" spec="1.3.3" source="pgb" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" spec="0.5.0" source="pgb" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
-->
```

**WITH THIS**

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file"           source="npm" spec="2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer"  source="npm" spec="1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"    source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser"   source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"      source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
```

### 3. Your 3rd-party plugins likely need replacement.

I've updated all your 3rd-party plugins.
If they fail to build or don't work, go back to your original setting.
The explanation is long as to why they may not work.

**THIRD-PARTY PLUGINS**

```
<!-- https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk -->
<plugin name="com.paypal.cordova.mobilesdk"  source="npm" spec="3.1.9" />
<!-- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" spec="5.0.7" />
<!-- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-datepicker -->
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker"  source="npm" spec="0.9.3" />
<!-- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-email-composer -->
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" source="npm" version="0.8.2" />
```

### 4. You need to implement the `whitelist` system

You need to implement the *whitelist* system.
This *whitelist* worksheet should help. 
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

In the meantime, to get thing working do the following.
**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**

**Add the following to your `config.xml`**

**CHANGE**

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

**Add the following to your `index.html`**

**UPDATE: 2015-12-01** Previously, I had forgotten to add a wild-card (`*`) to the `CSP` meta tag. I am now including this. This meta tag should be added to the header of the `index.html` file that is playing the audio.

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have removed 1 as suggested. I, then, proceeded to update all my core plugins and 3rd party plugins and assumed I would get some errors, but got none; so that went smoothly. In 4, I did already have <access origin="*" />, but didn't have the other parameters and added those too. I used the same meta tag posted, but added exceptions for youtube and google maps api scripts. After doing all that I was hoping this would fix the issue, but the plugin still doesn't fire up. I'm not sure what where else to look into. Thanks a lot, though! I know those are important.

Comment: I have not given up yet. Let me keep looking. I'll get back to you in an hour.

Comment: Okay, one last idea. First, I don't do Angular, so I have limited comment on that. However, there is a lot of overhead in your controller. Could you try making a transaction without the controller overhead, just to check the network connection?

Comment: Just tried that and no go. The weird part is that I get no console errors, so no idea what's wrong. I used this git and followed it to a T here: https://gist.github.com/Urbiwanus/c1e456f889f53e940a11 and created a factory as well as calling the function in a controller. Thanks again for all the suggestions.

Comment: Hmmmm.. Just had another idea. Sometimes the plugin is meant for a version of the compiler that *Phonegap Build* does not have YET! For instance, PGB `cli-5.2.0` is pinned to (iOS/Android/Windows) (3.9.1 / 4.1.1 / 3.8.1). But the latest release by [Cordova `CLI 5.4.0`](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/11/24/tools-release.html) puts (iOS/Android/Windows) at (3.9.2/4.1.1/3.8.1) AND [leading edge](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/) is (3.9.2/5.0.0/4.2.0). A fix I've seen applied on [Nitobi](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi) is to use a plugin one (1) or two (2) versions back

Comment: @user3839044,  I found an error in my `CSP` which may explain why you are not getting sound. Previously, I had `script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';`. I did not have the wild card for loading the network. It should have been `script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';`. I found this out about an hour ago testing a new App. I am surprised no one has mentioned it until now. Let me know. I'm adding this to my original answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I tried the new cli without using phonegap build, but the problem persisted, but I think I might be getting somewhere when you mentioned versions... I'm looking into that. Will also correct my meta tag as well, thanks for the revision!

Comment: Do you have a simpler example for Paypal? I got some [sound for a game working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949879/phaser-html5-app-cannot-play-sound-after-porting-by-phonegap-cloud-build/33969077#33969077). I'm starting to thing this might be just as easy. I got an app working in less than an hour. His biggest issued turns out to be - he is running Android 4.4.4, which I think is confusing the audio library. My phone was 5.1.1.

Comment: somebody know why does amount is reinit to $1 if it is a big amount (like $1900) ? thanks