# Looping Audio in Ionic Cordova Media

Tags: android, cordova, audio, ionic-framework, media

I wanted to loop the audio infinitely because it will act as background music. I tried to use the callback when success and callback status but it didn't play the audio again.

Here is the code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var src = "/android_asset/www/audio/bgmusic.mp3";
    var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(src, mediaSuccess, null, mediaStatusCallback);

    $scope.playBG = function() {
        media.setVolume(0.5);
        media.play();
    };

    $scope.pauseMedia = function() {
        media.pause();
    };

    $scope.stopMedia = function() {
        media.stop();
    };

    var mediaSuccess = function() {
        media.setVolume(0.5);
        media.play();
        $scope.playBG();
    }

    var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
        if(status == 4) {
            media.setVolume(0.5);
            media.play();
            $scope.playBG();
        }else{
            media.setVolume(0.5);
            media.play();
            $scope.playBG();
        }
    }

    $scope.$on('destroy', function() {
        media.release();
    });

    $scope.playBG();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with media.seekTo(0); ?

Comment: not yet but why will it seek to 0? how will it execute to play the audio again?

Comment: I'm hoping someone could check this out. Really need it ASAP. :) Thanks!

Comment: @BLNK are you get any solution?

Comment: @Neotrixs none as of now

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927316/how-to-loop-a-audio-in-phonegap